# Rails 3 : Mass-assignment with ActiveAdmin and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-one, mass-assignment, activeadmin

I am developing a rails application in which I have two models `User` and `Client`.
`User` is backed by devise and is responsible for authentication and `has_one` `Client` which holds the client details for a given user. This relation is always present as I ensure that a `Client` model is created whenever I create a `User`.

For the administration area I am using `ActiveAdmin`. Now, when I try to create a `User` through the administration interface I use a form like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs :username, :email, :password
  f.inputs :name => "Client", :for => :client do |client|
    client.inputs :name, :address, ...
  end
end
```

The problem is that either the `User` nor the `Client` are saved and the page is reloaded with validation errors. I have checked rails console and there's a `WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: client_attributes` message every time I try to create a `User`.

I have searched over this issue and found that in order to allow for mass-assignment one had to define `attr_accessible` for each of the fields allowed for the assignment. So, I had put this directive in `Client` model for each of the fields mentioned above and the message keeps appearing, preventing the models to be properly saved.

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: Did you restart your server after adding the attr_accessible?

Comment: Yes. The problem of mass-assignment was solved with Thomas Watson answer. However I still can't create the `User` and `Client`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not in your `Client` model, but in your `User` model - because this is the primary model you are trying to create. All you need to do is to add `client_attributes` to the list of `attr_accessible` attributes in your `User` model, just as the error message in the log files says, e.g.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_attributes
end
```

I imagine you already have a list of accessible attributes in the `User` class. So just add `client_attributes` to the end of that list.

The changes you made to your `Client` model (i.e. adding a list of attributes to `attr_accessible`) is not needed for this to work. If you want, you can also go ahead and undo that.

Comment: I have done what you told me to do and that suppresses the mass-assignment warning. However, it does not validate the client yet, redirecting me back to the `create user` with validation errors.

Comment: Update: I can edit an exiting User already. But I still can't create a new one.

Comment: If not all validation errors show, you can add <%= @user.errors.messages.inspect %> to the top of the page your are redirected back to. This will display the errors array containing all your errors

Comment: Sorry I took so long to answer. I actually solved the problem. The solution lies in what you said, but I had an 'after_initialize' callback to create the nested Client resource, which cleared the attributes sent by the browser before the save action happened. +1 for your solution though!

Comment: Doesn't this make user.client exposed to form-inject attacks?